# Positioning a DIV in one place so browser window size doesn't effect it

Tags: css

I've got a DIV on to the top of my webpage called #cube.

As you can see at the example below it's the red TC on the top of the menu bar. I'm trying to figure out how to position it so it stays in one place on the window resize:

[image]

Here is the CSS for #cube at the moment:

```
#cube{
background: url(../images/logo-cube.png) no-repeat;
width: 129px;
height: 131px;
z-index: 9999px;
position: relative;
top: 20px;
left: 500px;
}
```

Some help in the right direction with what I need to do with my CSS would very much be appreciated.

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: Without seeing the HTML and the rest of the CSS it is hard to say.  What is the parent container?  What is the positioning on the parent? When you set relative positioning on an element it sets that element relative to the closest non statically positioned ancestor.  If nothing else is non statically positioned your div is likely being anchored on the body tag.  If you do have a containing div setting position relative on that will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Hey @Jrod take a look at http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/textcube/.

Comment: The quickest fix I can see would be to place your cube div inside of `navbar-inner`.  Give `navbar-inner` position relative and give your cube position absolute.  You will need to tweak the values for your cube div to position it where you want but after that you should be good to go.  On a side note, I like your logo.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and compliment on the logo. It worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to position it using top and right, not top and left, then it'll follow the right hand edge.

I suspect you'll want to use `position: absolute;` while you're at it too.

Comment: Thanks, tried that. Take a look at http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/textcube/ where you can see the change. One thing with doing that is that it needs to remain within are 912px width area on the centre of the page and this goes to the top right of the browser window and moves as I resize the window.

Comment: Sorry, was in bed shortly after answering — see you got it going though :)

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file you have this

```
top: 20px;
right: 20px;
```

Remove the px from the top and right

Should be

```
#cube{
background: url(../images/logo-cube.png) no-repeat;
width: 129px;
height: 131px;
z-index: 9999px;
position: absolute;
top: 20;
right: 20;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael Howey I just tried what you said and uploaded it here http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/textcube/. Don't see any major change and it's not ending up like the illustrated example. Any further thoughts? Thanks, Tim